# Active Record how to preload join for scoped relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Thanks for taking a look at my question. I'm working on a Rails 5 API and am having trouble with a specific query.

My db has 2 models - players and battles. The battles table has 2 foreign key references to players as 'winner_id' and 'loser_id'. I also have a scope to include the winner and loser called 'with_results':

```
# models/battle.rb
class Battle < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to: winner,
    class_name: "Player",
    foreign_key: "winner_id"

  belongs_to: loser,
    class_name: "Player",
    foreign_key: "loser_id"

  scope :with_results, -> { includes(:winner, :loser) }

end
```

So what I am trying to achieve is getting the battle table, the winner's Player table, and the loser's Player table in one query.

In the rails console I have tried a few things:

```
Battle.first
# => returns just the battle table with the id's of the winner and loser

Battle.with_results.first
# => returns the same as `Battle.first`

Battle.first.winner
# => returns the winner's Player table

Battle.first.loser
# => returns the loser's Player table

Battle.joins(:winner, :loser).first
# => returns the same as `Battle.first`
```

Again, what I am trying to do is get the battle, the winner, and the loser in just one query so I can send out the JSON for it. Is there a way to preload the winner and loser with a scope so that I can have it all in one query?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there! Just tell `to_json` to include associations. For example:

```
Battle.with_results.first.to_json(include: [:winner, :loser])
```

Comment: Thank you it works! Just a follow up question - how could you add all of that to the scope if you wanted to keep the controller as skinny as possible?

Comment: @JaredMurphy: the scope you have on the model has the effect of *eager loading*. The `include` on `to_json` is separate to this, and needs to be specified outside of the scope. If you wanted to tidy things up, then consider adding `to_json(include: [:winner, :loser])` as an new method on `Battle`